# Stack unwinding support?

Tags: linux, arm, busybox

I have built a minimal Busybox initramfs system for armv6l. Kernel version is 3.12.20. If I compile the kernel without `CONFIG_ARM_UNWIND | Enable stack unwinding support (EXPERIMENTAL)` then connect to the system via SSH and run this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

while :
do
    dmesg
done
```

the message 'Killed' will show on the screen after a short time, and the system becomes unusable. If I look at the console, I see the OOM killer has killed /bin/sh. I do not have to run the script to trigger this behaviour, sometimes the SSH connection will be disconnected almost immediately after logging in.

I'm able to log into the system after that, but the shell is not available so I cannot run any commands. However, running the script will always trigger the problem. I have made some tests and found out that right before the OOM killer kills the shell, almost all the 512 MB RAM is free so there are no reason for OOM killer to kill anything.

After doing some research, I still do not understand what stack unwinding support is, but the feature is EXPERIMENTAL so I would not expect it to be required for my system to be useable.

Can anyone explain why this feature is required for a functional system?

Comment: There are various features that depend on `UNWIND` support.  In fact, if you do not select `UNWIND`, [then another mechanism is used](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/Kconfig.debug#n31) (Ie, RMK will have to kill you; meaning the ARM Linux maintainer).  If you compile without, and the *bug* doesn't trigger, then the `UNWIND` is probably an innocent victim of the *real bug*; for instance a stack overflow.  There is really too little information; unless you only want the part with the '?' answered?  In fact, your compiler used will play into this.

Comment: Most likely, the repeated `dmesg` is causing some sort of race.  A real problem is occurring; kernel task SEGV and then the unwinding will try to print diagnostics.  At this point, you are constantly accessing the log that wants to print this information.  A serial console would be better mechanism.  Your SSH is relying on a lot of functionality; networks stack, driver, user space sshd, etc.  The serial console will print out the error without running a constant `dmesg`.

Comment: The OOM can be invoked even if you have lots of *free memory*.  A `kmalloc()` with a large size can require contiguous memory.  The allocator may run the OOM killer in this case.  For instance if different pools are exhausted or a driver used >4k allocations.

Answer (score 0):

This is from [arch/arm/Kconfig.debug](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/Kconfig.debug#L45)

```
config ARM_UNWIND
    bool "Enable stack unwinding support (EXPERIMENTAL)"
    depends on AEABI && EXPERIMENTAL
    default y
    help
      This option enables stack unwinding support in the kernel
      using the information automatically generated by the
      compiler. The resulting kernel image is slightly bigger but
      the performance is not affected. Currently, this feature
      only works with EABI compilers. If unsure say Y.
```

So in generally any arm kernel should be able to run without ARM_UNWIND support however of course there might be some cases where your setup triggers an uncommon bug but I don't think this is the case for you.

Check the kernel logs for what you can learn about the problem.